# Error en los providers flutter: Couldn't interfer type parameter 'T'

Tags: android, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

estoy haciendo una app de ecommerce en flutter, cuando trato de hacer los providers para las categorias me lanzaba este error: type 'AsyncSnapshot' is not a subtype of type 'List'y la manera que en contre la solucion fue añadiendo esta linea de codigo a la hora de llamarlos desde firestore: (context, AsyncSnapshot), pero ahora me lanza un nuevo error, esta es la manera en que tengo implementada la parte del codigo:

```
return FutureBuilder(
                  // ignore: deprecated_member_use
                  future: Firestore.instance
                      .collection("category")
                      // ignore: deprecated_member_use
                      .document("4ton5n1tQBHMnJ5jmJ4l")
                      .collection("alarmas")
                      // ignore: deprecated_member_use
                      .getDocuments(),
                  builder:
                      (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Product>> alarmasSnapshot) {
                    if (alarmasSnapshot.connectionState ==
                        ConnectionState.waiting) {
                      return Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                      );
                }
```

Alguna idea? El error que me sale este: Couldn't interfer type parameter 'T'

Comment: No se si tu error sea por que intentas obtener un `AsyncSnapshot<List<Product>>` y  `getDocuments()`, lo que te regresaría seria un `QuerySnapshot`, y dentro de tu `Asyncsnapshot`, tienes que acceder a la propiedad `alarmasSnapshot.docs` , que es donde están tus documentos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te recomendaría usar un StreamBuilder en lugar de un FutureBuilder algo así como esto:

```
StreamBuilder(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('tucoleccion')
          .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid)
          .collection('tuotracoleccion')
          .snapshots(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.waiting:
            return Center(
                child: Column(
              children: [
                CircularProgressIndicator(),
                Text('Cargando...'),
              ],
            ));

            break;
          default:
            return ListView(
              children: snapshot.data.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document) {
                return Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      RaisedButton(
                          child: Text(document['Campos del Documento'],
                          onPressed: () async {
                          }),
                    ],
                  );
              
              }).toList(),
            );
        }
      },
    );
```

También debes revisar las versiones de los plugins que estas usando, los nuevos cambiaron su nomenclatura, el código que te envié aplica a las nuevas versiones.